# .net Generation (CLR or GC)?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, clr

is it CLR that uses the "Generation mechanism" to improve the performance of finding unreachable objects?

I know what generations are, however not quite sure which part of the .net platform utilizes it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the current CLI GC uses a generational model, but this is an implementation detail. It is not *required* to do that - and there are implementations (MicroFramework, possibly XNA, etc) that do *not* do this